# Is Twisted available for Python3?

Tags: raspbian, python

I would like to install the Twisted Python library for Python 3 but it seems that on Raspbian it only targets Python 2; is that right?

I've tried installing it through both `apt-get install python-twisted` and `pip install twisted`, but when I run Python 3.4.2 and try to load it, the library is not found (`ImportError`) whereas on Python 2.7 it's correctly imported. How is that? Is it possible to get it for the latest version of the language?

Comment: did u try sudo apt-get install python-twisted
because that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no twisted package for python 3 in Raspbian wheezy or jessie.

There is a python3-twisted package in Raspbian stretch.

As for pip it seems that there are seperate versions for each python version. I belive you want to run pip3 to install stuff for the default python3 version.